# Speed of propagation of gravity in full non-linear theory

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

It is often stated that gravity propagates at the speed of light. Justifications for that statement usually follow from the linearized theory, for which it is more or less obvious. However, I was wondering how exactly it follows from the full non-linear theory. What I'm wondering is, if there is some perturbation in the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, how quickly does information of that disturbance spread through the gravitational field?

One issue I have is that I'm not entirely sure what "propagate at the speed of light" means in general relativity, due to speed itself being somewhat ill-defined without a background metric. Maybe it suffices to show it holds in some sense at least locally, maybe the question is meaningless.

I tried one approach without success. From the field equations, it's logical that $R_{\mu\nu}$ cannot propagate faster than $c$, in fact it doesn't propagate at all, it's completely determined by the stress-energy tensor. The Weyl tensor describes how gravity propagates in vacuum. With some judicious use of the Bianchi identities, it should be possible to express its divergence $\nabla_\mu C^{\mu}_{\ \nu\kappa\lambda}$ solely in terms of the stress-energy tensor, but I'm unsure if this implies anything about the speed of propagation.

Comment: One can show that (in an appropriately chosen gauge, and evolution scheme) the metric at a point depends only on the metric in its own past lightcone. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds close to what I'm looking for